# How to make if statement inside if(condition & condition & if())?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a condition: if login, password and email aren't empty run the following code, but if someone inputs 'admin' in login and password I want the code to skip empty email and go ahead. I'm getting the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\signup.php on line 16
```

My code:

```
$dblogin=$_POST["login"];
$dbpassword=$_POST["password"];
$dbemail=$_POST["email"];
$connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'data');
$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
if(mysqli_connect_errno()==0){
       if((!empty($_POST[login])) && (!empty($_POST[password])) && if($login!=admin & $password!=admin){(!empty($_POST[email]))}){
           $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT FROM users (dblogin, dbpassword, dbemail) WHERE dblogin=login");
```

Comment: You can use ternary I suspect, but better and easier all around just to nest the if statements.

Comment: You can not use if inside of an if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite it in something like that:

```
 if((!empty($_POST[login])) && 
      (!empty($_POST[password])) && 
         ($login!="admin" && $password!="admin" && !empty($_POST[email])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

```
if($login!=admin & $password!=admin)
```

`&` is a bitwise operator, not an and.  I'm assuming this is not what you want.

```
if((!empty($_POST[login])) && (!empty($_POST[password])) && if($login!=admin & $password!=admin)
```

You don't need another if here, the if is already implied because you're using `&&` (and)...